# Can't find Brown University Nao package

Tags: camera, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I want to use Nao camera, but can't find Brown University Nao package.

How can I use Nao camera? Please tell me.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34398/can%27t-find-brown-university-nao-package/) by [Yusuke Furuta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2415/yusuke-furuta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2012-05-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yusuke Furuta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2415/yusuke-furuta/) on 2012-05-27**:
Dear daniel_maier.

Thank you for your answer.

If possible, please fix camera_info in order to use image_proc.

**Comment by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) on 2012-05-28**:
what exactly is broken? If you leave the resolution at QVGA, everything should work with image_proc. I just added a set_camera_info service, so you can send your own CameraInfo msg to nao_camera.py. This service is necessary for camera_calibration, I think. There is an example set_camera_info.py in nao_drivers for how to call the service.

**Comment by [Yusuke Furuta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2415/yusuke-furuta/) on 2012-05-28**:
Because camera_info in original program is insufficient, image_proc dosen't publish /imgae_rect_color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Feel free to try out our new nao_camera.py wrapper in alufr-ros-pkg (http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao_robot).
I think Brown University do no develop software for Nao anymore.

---

Originally posted by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) with karma: 290 on 2012-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3